# How to specify the file name while uploading a file to Google Drive using the HTTP API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm uploading files to Google Drive using the HTTP API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

I'm posting the file content to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files` and it's working fine.

However, I can't find anywhere how to specify the file name. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should send the file metadata together with the file content and set the `title` property to specify the file name:

```
{
  "title": "My File"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Claudio. But I saw it in the decumentation and didn't understand. How can I send the file metadata together with the content? In the POST request I can only pass headers and the file as content.

Comment: You have to send a multipart request or implement the resumable upload protocol. With simple upload you can't set the file metadata while uploading, but you can always use 2 requests: one to upload the file and another one to rename the file you just uploaded.