# Example not the format for Request raw Body for uploading a File in google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Whatever data I want to send whether be a text file or a PDF am able to give but how do I give my desired name to the file ?? And what about other types of files ?? What should be the request header please give an example had a look at the API documentation but not getting it ...

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have currently tried, and describe any issues you are having with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using a basic upload.

You can use the suggested answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387892/how-to-specify-the-file-name-while-uploading-a-file-to-google-drive-using-the-ht):

Use multipart upload and specify the tile in the metadata part

```
{
  "title": "My File"
}
```

Types of files are called MiME types. You can see the supported MiME types [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).

Check this [Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload) guide for more info.